# Samsung galaxy phones shuts down automatically

Tags: crashes, samsung-galaxy-note, shutdown

I own a Samsung Galaxy Note. I have seen that very randomly and infrequently, my device just turns off on its own. I then have to restart it by pressing on the power button.

Yes, the device has enough battery life left in it.

I have seen the same behaviour in my previous Samsung Galaxy S as well. 
Any one out here experiencing the same, or does any one know why its happening and what I could do to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same behaviour, related to frequent "driving mode" madness. I don't know if the driving mode is an effect of the same cause or not, but when one stopped the other did too.

What I did to stop it (some might be BS, but It didn't do it a second time, so I can't find out what was the help)

- Dry it off (some rain might have gotten into the USB port)
- Clean the usb port.
- Shut off, remove battery, wait 10 minutes
- Restart.
- Connect to wall-outlet-charger (full charge, as opposed to computer charge)
- Stop charging it with el cheapo, very thin, shaky cables.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah My Samsung Galaxy S2 behave like that sometimes... I thought I pressed the power button for quite too long (I was using an annoying skin fit cover). But now that you mention it, Yes it happens. But ever since I am using Amzer covers there has never been a problem like that. Yes the some weird app eats up memories and shuts down the phone, but it is not turning off anymore.

Comment: I have upgraded to ICS and havent seen this bug since then.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is a "Loose " battery issue. I had the same problem with my galaxy xcover and cured it totally by adding a layer of thick adhesive tape at the end of the battery in order to press it harder against the contacts, and 2 layers of adhesive tape at the back of the battery in order to keep it more firmly in place.
Problem solved !!

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the phone rebooting apparently without any cause about once a day, I only realized that because it played the boot sound. I think that was because the case I use might fit a little bit too tight and in some situations pressed the power button for a long time which, if I do that intentionally also initializes a reboot.

I have adjusted the case and haven't experienced the problem since then.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about other Galaxy devices but the Note 2 shuts off on it's own under various conditions, all hardware related. Take a look at this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjLn2yikYnI and also this site I built that goes in to more detail regarding the issue: www.GalaxyNote2ShutsOff.com

One look at that short video and I am sure there will be some light bulbs going off. Be sure to read the details I provided on that site as well. They go in to detail about the problems that I have had and the lack of proper support that Samsung is willing to provide.

Answer (score -1):

When you put wifi in sleepy condition, it keeps CPU busy & overloaded putting wifi on and off frequently, so putting wifi never sleepy condition the CPU is less burdened & more efficient, which ensures phone never shutdown on its own.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! I very much doubt it will "overload" the CPU, nor will it make the device "never shutdown on its own" (if the battery is empty, it will still do so). I can't even see how this is connected to the issue; mind to explain?

Answer (score -2):

i had the same problem , my phone switches off and on for about 20-25 times a day ,,
horrible isnt it ,
well .. !!
this is wat i did to over come this problem , and it worked fine .
go to 
**settings > wireless and network > wifi settings > using menu option choose advance settings >wifi sleep policy > select "never" > press menu option and save** ..
have happy time :)

Comment: What does the sleep policy have to do with shutdowns? This seems like a red herring.